# Publish project with build in VS2012 Fails with "Skipping unpublishable project"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, msdeploy

I am migrating current solution from VS2010 to VS2012, since web deployment projects are not supported i am trying "Publish" feature on the project.

My requirement is to run "Publish" on the project while running the build. This is a ".csproj" with publish method "File System" also on settings tab of publish i have "Precompile during Publishing" and "Merge all outputs into single assembly".

I can manually run publish by right clicking on project and selecting "Publish" and it gives desired single assembly and copies it to right location, i just need this to run on build

I have tried following to no avail

Adding single line to .csproj file

```
    <DeployOnBuild>true</DeployOnBuild>
```

tried adding following lines to .csproj

```
<FilesToIncludeForPublish>OnlyFilesToRunTheApp</FilesToIncludeForPublish>
<DeployOnBuild>true</DeployOnBuild>
<DeployTarget>Package</DeployTarget>
<PackageAsSingleFile>true</PackageAsSingleFile>
```

Command line

```
MSBuild C:\MyProj.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=WebDeploy /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0
```

Above command results in

```
Build started 07/04/2014 14:01:05.
Project "C:\MyProj.csproj" on node 1 (default targets).
Build:
Running Publish
_DeploymentUnpublishable:
Skipping unpublishable project.
Done Building Project "C:\MyProj.csproj" (default targets).
Build succeeded.
```

Comment: This seems crazy but you could try and get msdeploy to do it for you.. I think it accepts a parameter for a VS publish file. Check out the MSDN for msdeploy command line arguments

Comment: @Michael Dont get why this is crazy..i am just porting over same project functionality from VS2010 on to 2012. I need to replace the merge and xcopy step of web deployment project with "Publish" feature of VS2012.

Comment: The crazy part was using msdeploy.. I'm not sure if it will work but it will run any transform scripts etc.. that you may need and stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my surprise it turned out to be **McAfee antivirus** which is messing up "Publish" here, i was doing things right and it all works fine with McAfee turned off, somehow the antivirus stops the aspnet_compiler.exe to pre-compile the site and as a result the pre-compilation and subsequent merge steps(merge dlls into single assembly) fails, hope no one goes through same pain to find this out.

Comment: so which of the 4 provided solutions did actually work?

Answer (score 5):

I'm glad you solved your problem, but I kept ending up here with my own searches, and it definitely wasn't McAfee (or any antivirus software) that was getting in my way.  So for anyone else who ends up here, here's what eventually worked for me:

I realized that I was doing `/t:Publish` instead of `/t:Package` on the command line.  Switching that bypassed the "Skipping unpublishable project" step.

The final command line should look like this (formatted for readability):

```
MSBuild C:\MyProj.csproj 
   /p:DeployOnBuild=true 
   /p:PublishProfile=WebDeploy 
   /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 
   /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0
   /p:OutputPath="bin\\"
   /t:Package
```

Comment: Be sure you are using `/t:Package` against your web .csproj and not your .sln

Comment: Why would `/t:Publish` be the problem and why is `/t:Package` better?

Comment: @crush - Good question.  I don't think I ever figured that out, or if I did I've since forgotten it.  I'd guess that `/t:Package` stops one step earlier in the process, and that last step isn't something that `msbuild` thinks it can handle, so it just skips the whole thing.

Comment: @Bobson It seems that package target just packages it into a zip file. I'm trying to use web deploy, which requires the publish target. Problem is I'm getting that stupid "Skipping unpublishable project." message. I'm trying to build once, and publish to multiple locations, and it's a freaking nightmare. I've lost so much time on this, I'm about to lose my mind

Comment: @crush - If you're using `CreatePackageOnPublish=True`, isn't that zip file what you want?  If you want it actually pushed out, you might be able to use `/t:Publish` without that flag and have it work.  But in my case, I specifically needed the zip dropped into a specific location and not a full remote web deploy.  Alternatively, you can turn the logging up to the most verbose and maybe see what's causing it to skip?

Comment: @crush - I also suggest looking through `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets`, which seems to be where the "unpublishable" error message is generated.  At a quick glance, it looks like web projects are _specifically_ not publishable with the publish task.  I wonder if the "Publish" task is unrelated to the "Publish" command in the UI?

Answer (score 1):

Using MSBuild.exe command line, you can specify the output path like below:
You will explore on c:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin ,Then you run this command:

```
.\MSBuild.exe [path of your project]/[projectName].csproj /P:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU / p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:outdir="c:\output\\"  /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
```

Please pay attention that you must create the  **output** folder.
If you are going to build all projects on solution you have to use below command:

```
 .\MSBuild.exe [path of your project]/[solutionName].sln /P:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:outdir="c:\output\\"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the cause was this line in my .csproj:

```
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
```

I changed it to be a Case Sensitive match with the rules in Microsoft.Common.targets:

```
<OutputType>winexe</OutputType>
```

I it worked!