# MSBuild publish not working for Office VSTO

Tags: c#, msbuild, continuous-integration, vsto, office-addins

I have been going crazy trying to fix this publishing issue for days. I have a VSTO application for Office that builds using MSbuild.exe successfully, in both debug and release. The problem arises when I try to run MSbuild like such: `MSBuild -t:publish`.  The funny thing is, when I use the publishing wizard in Visual Studio 2019 Community, my application publishes properly. **I only have issues when trying to use MSBuild.exe with the publish target, not with normal builds.**

[image: By right clicking my project and clicking Publish, I see this wizard which produces the expected result.]

By right-clicking my project in VS 2019 and clicking Publish, I see this wizard which produces the expected result.

## Expected Result:

MSbuild produces a `publish` directory with a .vsto file for my application along with a a reference directory with dependencies and/or a setup.exe
[image: The expected result of running MSbuild with the publish target.]

The expected result of running MSbuild with the publish target.

## Actual Result:

When running `MSBuild -t:publish` in a command line that is CD'ed to the directory of my project, I get this error:

```
Project "D:\repositories\myapp\myapp.sln" (1) is building "D:\repositories\myapp\myapp
.csproj" (2) on node 1 (Publish target(s)).
_DeploymentUnpublishable:
  Skipping unpublishable project.
```

## Things I tried:

I tried a lot of things to get this to work. I read these threads:

[First thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914009/publish-project-with-build-in-vs2012-fails-with-skipping-unpublishable-project) : Applies to ASP.net applications not VSTO, also says that McAfee can cause issues. I disabled all antivirus on my machine, still no luck. I have tried adding properties such as: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true` `/p:OutputPath="publish/"` `/p:PublishDir="publish"` `/p:VisualStudioVersion=16.11` (my version) and all combinations of these and it never worked. I tried using `/t:Package` but I get the error:  `error MSB4057: The target "Package" does not exist in the project.`

Adding `<OutputType>winexe</OutputType>` to my .csproj does not work because this application produces a DLL on normal builds, not an executable.

[Second thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/fd391a80-aa41-49cf-91c5-831efbb5752b/vs-build-tools-2017-for-office-vsto?forum=msbuild)
I already have this installed. I'm testing the command line publish on my local development machine before I try this on the build server.

[Third thread](http://www.databaseforum.info/8/1020719.aspx) I am not using a shared add-in.

[Fourth Thread](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/1901) ITT and others, they recommend using a .pubxml but I cannot figure out how to make one of those, AFAIK they are generated by ASP.net applications and not applicable to a VSTO application. I could be wrong, but again I don't know how to create one properly.

[Fifth Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ff624126(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) This is a lot of stuff to do, and I am confused if it will even work. I DO have VS 2019 installed, my program builds successfully and runs successfully, and even publishes successfully when using the publishing wizard. I am not using TFS. I am just trying to produce the VSTO via command line.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this problem, it is because you are not loading:

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets`

I wish the log would have been more specific about that.